# Saving form data from html to server side

Tags: javascript, html, apache, cgi, solaris-10

I have an apache installed in Solaris 10. I want to make an html page that takes in user data in a text box and saves it in a location in my apache(server side). I have limitation to use only JavaScript or call an shell script. Help required on the java script and the configuration changes in httpd.conf and virtualhost.conf

Comment: Your question is too broad and the answer too complex to be answered on this site. I highly recommend you look for YouTube videos on these topics.

Comment: "I have limitation to use only JavaScript or call an shell script." — This doesn't make much sense. Are you talking about server side JavaScript? Apache doesn't play too well with that. Are you talking about client side Javascript? That would usually fit with "and" not "or" in the sentence I quoted.

Comment: "use only JavaScript" — You're already using HTML. Why are you rejecting an ordinary HTML form submission?

Comment: "the configuration changes in httpd.conf and virtualhost.conf" — Have you done any research on how to configure Apache to run CGI programs? Apache has a good manual with a section on CGI.

Comment: "call an shell script" — This is a weird restriction. Shell is not a particularly common programming language for CGI … and Perl and Python are readily available on most systems. (Which shell anyway? Bourne? Bash? Zsh? Tcsh?)

Comment: I am a beginner in this field, i could redefine my question like : Is it possible to make a text file on the server side with the user's input from a html page hosted on the same server(apache)